# Specific .resx file per client in .net 5 mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, resx

Looking for a way to do specific .resx overrides for a client based on some sort of identifier.

[image]

So the nl-BE-6 should be accessed first and in case the key is not found, look for it in nl-BE and lastly in the global .resx file.

I tried setting them in the startup:

[image]

And this worked for setting the culture/ui culture

[image]

But the nl-BE-6.resx is not used.

Is there a way to make this work or maybe another workaround?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs to know, this is how I solved it for now.

Override both IStringLocalizerFactory & IStringLocalizer.

That way I can still use Globalizer and Localizer.

Works pretty good